# set a chosen image-file-input as a featured image from wp frontend

Tags: image, wordpress, forms

**SCENARIO** : I allow to create posts from front-end. The form also has four image upload fields. I use the code pasted below for image attachments and setting the post thumbnail.

```
//insert attachments
    if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
        }
        } 


 //attachment helper function   
 function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK){ return __return_false(); 
        } 
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

        $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
        //set post thumbnail
        if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id); //you will need to comment out this line if you use my solution
        return $attach_id;//you will need to comment out this line if you use my solution
            }
```

The post-thumbnail/featured image that is set through this code is the LAST image that is uploaded. I tried a google search for "set post thumbnail from frontend wordpress" and grazed through a lot of articles but none came close to what I am asking here. Majority of threads I came across at SE in regards to front-end posting, either talks about setting the featured image or about multiple uploads. I have also checked all the suggested questions which were prompted, while I was writing this question just to make sure if it has been asked before.

If it matters, here is the html that is used in the form, pretty standard.

```
<input type="file" name="image-one" id="image-one"/>
<input type="file" name="image-two" id="image-two"/>
<input type="file" name="image-three" id="image-three"/>
```

REQUEST : It would be great if I could get a solution that helps to assign any chosen image-input-field as a featured-image but at this moment, at least what I need to set the FIRST image input to be set as a featured-image/post-thumbnail. Kindly suggest a solution.

> Bottomline is that I do not have an issue with setting post-thumbnail
>   but question is about having a choice to choose any of the uploaded
>   images as post-thumbnail or at least the first image, instead of the
>   last image as set by the current code.

---

**PROGRESS REPORT** : 
Never know if it would help in cracking this issue. But when I print_($newupload), I get the id eg. 54287 ,of the last-image-input attachment that is saved as post-thumbnail.

[This thread](http://www.wphike.com/519/first-image-featured-image/) suggests a way to set a featured-image with the first image found in the post so I thought of working on that idea. But the code does not seem to work either.

```
$attachments = get_children(array(
            'post_parent' => $pid, 
            'post_status' => 'inherit', 
            'post_type' => 'attachment', 
            'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'orderby' => 'ID'
        ));
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                set_post_thumbnail($pid, $attachment->ID);
                break;
            }
```

---

**FINAL WORD** : The code in the progress report momentarily gets the job done for me, that is.. setting the first image-file-input as a featured-image/post-thumbnail and I am not even sure if this is the best way to do this. I am still looking for a solution which could give a flexibility to choose any image-input-field as a featured-image. If you decide to use this feature remember to comment out the second last and third last lines from the original code.

Comment: How is the last image being set as the thumbnail? do you ever send the third parameter to your function? what happens if you change your call inside the loop to this: `$newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid,$file=='image-one');`?

Comment: @koala_dev I do not know honestly, if there were parameters like you suggested ..I would have tried changing it. Anyways letme test ur suggestion, I will report back in a moment.

Comment: @koala_dev sorry, that did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Saving a post_meta with _thumbnail_id as meta_key and the attach_id as meta_value won't make that image a featured image, you can use [`wp_insert_attachment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) that will help you a lot in this. Make sure you read the codex and the examples there. The function should be used in conjunction with [wp_update_attachment_metadata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_attachment_metadata) and [wp_generate_attachment_metadata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) this way your feature image will be created properly by wordpress.

EDIT:
I've looked over your code and I'm gussing it's easier to use it then my schetch in this case. I've added a file count and a parameter to insert_attachment. Check this code let me know what happens.

Example:

```
<?php
//insert attachments
if ($_FILES) {
array_reverse($_FILES);
$i = 0;//this will count the posts
foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    if ($i == 0) $set_feature = 1; //if $i ==0 then we are dealing with the first post
    else $set_feature = 0; //if $i!=0 we are not dealing with the first post
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid, $set_feature);
    $i++; //count posts
    }
    } 


//attachment helper function   
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK){ return __return_false(); 
    } 
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
    //set post thumbnail if setthumb is 1
    if ($setthumb == 1) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
    return $attach_id;
        }
  ?>
```

Comment: I do not have an issue with setting post-thumbnail. The give code sets the featured-image but the issue is it only sets the LAST image as featured image, when I need either at least the first image to be set as featured or freedom to choose from any of the uploaded images. Thanks for your effort but I do not see how to set the chosen-image-input as a featured image.

Comment: you add only one image throw $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data ); for the rest you use update_post_meta() ... that should do it

Comment: I am pretty new to this, so it is hard to understand what you just suggested. Could you please do me a favor and make the correction in example code you already gave. So it is clear to me how it all is related. If you code works I guess I will have to get rid of my entire code. Please be thorough and explicit. Thank you.

Comment: it works but still fetches the last image as post-thumbnail. `print_r($new_upload)` still gives an id of the last uploaded image. eg. 25462

Comment: you are correct, media_handle_upload uses wp_insert_attachment and wp_update_attachment_metadata which overwrites the feature info each time.. I've made an edit to the post again that will reverse the $_FILE array so the 1st image is processed last and it's value will be the last updated info

Comment: sorry, still the same result. But, I think your solution is almost there. Also please check my update if the idea I am trying is wrong. If you think it is a good idea please suggest a correction or else ignore it.

Comment: the code in the progress report seems to work but it has been setting post-thumbnail randomly till now. I am still looking if something is wrong due to "order" or "orderby" in the meanwhile I am waiting if you can solve your solution.

Comment: Yep, I seemed to be right. the oderby"ID" and order"ASC" did the trick. Before I write this as an answer in order to let people know looking for same feature, please let me know if this solution is advisable at all. Thanks for all the help @alex, really appreciated.

Comment: @gurung: yap your ideea is good, you use wordpress functions to achieve wich is very good (almost perfect) feel free to edit my answer if you need and if using order by can make things work without that array_revers($_FILES) it would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

We can set post featured image from frontend using following function, 
simple you need to call this function

post_imgs_update($new_post_id);

after creating new post. and add following function in functions.php

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_imgs_update' ) ) :
        function post_imgs_update($new_post_id) {

            $data = array();
            $attachment_ids = array();
            // code for save featured image
            if( isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'image_upload' ) ){  // here nonce text is "image_upload" you need to add in form
                    $files = reArrayFiles($_FILES['files']);

                if(!empty($_FILES['files'])){
                    //$i = 0; 
                    $set_featured_img = 0 ;

                    foreach( $files as $file ){
                        if( is_array($file) ){
                            $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file, basename($file['name']) );
                            if ( is_numeric($attachment_id) ) {
                                if ($set_featured_img == '0') {
                                    set_post_thumbnail($new_post_id, $attachment_id);
                                    $set_featured_img++;
                                    $attachment_ids[] = $attachment_id;
                                }
                                else{
                                    $attachment_ids[] = $attachment_id;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //add to array
                    $mediaurl = array();
                    foreach ($attachment_ids as $img_id) {
                        $imgurl = wp_get_attachment_url( $img_id );
                        $image_gallery[$img_id] = $imgurl;
                    }

                    update_post_meta( $new_post_id, '_stw_property_multi_images', $image_gallery);      // 2nd arg field key
                }

            } 
            else {
                    $data['status'] = false;
                    $data['message'] = __('Nonce verify failed','realestate');
            }

            return $new_post_id;

        }
    endif;

    if ( ! function_exists( 'reArrayFiles' ) ) :
        function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {
            $file_ary = array();
            $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
            $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);
            for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
                foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
                    $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
                }
            }
            return $file_ary;
        }
    endif;

    if ( ! function_exists( 'upload_user_file' ) ) :
        function upload_user_file( $file = array(), $title = false ) {
            require_once ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/admin.php';
            $file_return = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false));
            if(isset($file_return['error']) || isset($file_return['upload_error_handler'])){
                return false;
            }else{
                $filename = $file_return['file'];
                $attachment = array(
                    'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
                    'post_content' => '',
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'guid' => $file_return['url']
                );
                if($title){
                    $attachment['post_title'] = $title;
                }
                $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename );
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

                $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
                if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
                    return $attachment_id;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    endif;


    function my_handle_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$set_thu=false) {
        $attachurlarray = array();
        // check to make sure its a successful upload
        if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

        $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
        return $attach_id;  
    }
```